# not showing data using thickbox tb_inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, thickbox

I am using, thickbox in Joomla, have included jquery and thickbox files, and when I use iframe or ajax then every thing shows fine while if I try to show inline content in thickbox, it doesnot show any thing. Following is my code:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true"  class="thickbox" id="myLink">Show hidden modal content.</a>
 <div style="display:none" id="hiddenModalContent">This is the div that I want to show</div>
```

So where the problem is? I am using it in Joomla. It shows popup but nothing inside it, and it is really strange that this is not working in my code while working on thick box demo with same code, so please tell whatever you know.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you;
you have to warp content into another HTML element within the hiddin div:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true"  class="thickbox" id="myLink">Show hidden modal content.</a>
<div style="display:none" id="hiddenModalContent">
<div>This is the div that I want to show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try wrapping your content ("This is the div that I want to show") inside a blank div?

eg:

```
<div style="display:none" id="hiddenModalContent"><div>This is the div that I want to show</div></div>
```

Comment: What ever you put , div or text it is html in a container named hiddenModalContent , so that content is not being shown, it doesn't matter what the content is whether in one div or 2.

Comment: also if you want to ask questions then put comment under question